# (C++) Problem Calling backreference of pointer of dynamically allocated array element that only happens for 1D but not 2D

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

Here's the code.

test.h->

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

static int*** TESTER;
static int** TestAgain;

void init_test();
void call_tester();

void get_tester(int* letmebeit, int* metoo);

#endif
```

test.cc->

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>

void init_test() {
    int** somearray = new int* [3];
    somearray[0] = new int[2];
    somearray[1] = new int[2];
    somearray[2] = new int[2];
    somearray[2][1] = 3;

    int* smallerarray = new int[3];
    smallerarray[2] = 4;
    
    TESTER = &somearray;
    TestAgain = &smallerarray;
} 

void call_tester() {
    std::cout << (*TESTER)[2][1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << (*TestAgain)[2] << std::endl;
}

void get_tester(int* letmebeit, int* metoo) {
    *letmebeit = (*TESTER)[2][1];
    *metoo = (*TestAgain)[2];
}
```

main.cc->

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"



int main() {
    
    init_test();
    call_tester();

    int Exelcior;
    int WorkPLZ;

    get_tester(&Exelcior, &WorkPLZ);
    std::cout << Exelcior << std::endl;
    std::cout << WorkPLZ << std::endl;
}
```

2D array works as it spits out 3 correctly.
But pointer 1D array 'smallerarray' causes exception.

Weird thing is if I std::cout the element with
`std::cout << (*TestAgain)[2] << std::endl;`
first, so by changing
`void init_test()`
in test.cc to

```
void init_test() {
    int** somearray = new int* [3];
    somearray[0] = new int[2];
    somearray[1] = new int[2];
    somearray[2] = new int[2];
    somearray[2][1] = 3;

    int* smallerarray = new int[3];
    smallerarray[2] = 4;
    
    TESTER = &somearray;
    TestAgain = &smallerarray;
    std::cout << (*TestAgain)[2] << std::endl;
}
```

TestAgain would spit out correct value of 4 in `call_tester()`
and `get_tester()`.

I was expecting it would correctly get the value no matter whether I called it firstly in the function or not.

Please teach me what's happening here.

Comment: You're storing pointers to local variables, whose lifetimes end when the function returns. The behaviour of dereferencing them afterwards is undefined.

Comment: If you have a `static` variable in a header, and include it into two cpp files, they get two separate copies of the variable. (Edit: But perhaps not a problem here, if only one of the copies is actually used...)

Comment: Can you help me find out why 2D array works correctly and second situation weirdly works?

Comment: "It seems to work" is the most evil form of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Sir could you please explain why call_tester() would print 3 in the case of 2D array your comment has no information on that

Comment: @gusEk It was a coincidence - your program is not a valid C++ program. As the old saying goes, "undefined behaviour is undefined".

Comment: I just ran the program again. Even if I setted somearray[2][1] = 3125 it would still spit out correct answer of 3125

Comment: @molbdnilo I ran the program setting somearray[2][1] as random value 7 times. They all printed correct value. I really feel hard to believe that this is just mere coincidence.

Comment: @gusEk That you get the same value back is coincidental. You can't determine that it isn't by examining what the value is.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you for keep answering. I finally understood what you said and improved by adding a static class. I'm sorry I doubted you.